# How to use the Console in MSIE developer tools?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, developer-tools, ie11-developer-tools

When debugging on Chrome, I frequently use the console to execute JavaScript commands on the fly, e.g. to inspect variables at a breakpoint.

**How can I do the same in MSIE's dev tools?**

When I enter something into the console, such as

```
console.log('hello');
```

and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, the command duly appears in the console, but its output is nowhere to be seen:

[image: MSIE console, showing only commands, but no results of their execution]

EDIT: In a few cases, I have meanwhile managed to get some output right there in the console, as I would have expected. Even if that happened, it would only work for some five commands before the console would become rather "passive" again. Maybe I am doing something wrong (which should thus be a valid answer, as apparently I am somehow not yet meeting the prerequisites to effectively use the MSIE dev tools console), or maybe it is simply a severe stability issue in those dev tools.

Comment: Strange.... What does the Emulation tab of the IE dev tool say? eg. IE5 - Display intranet sites in compatibility view. Some features/commands of the IE dev tool may not be available if you are debugging an intranet or web page that is using a lower emulation mode. If possible include links to web pages or a jsfiddle with your questions.

Comment: @RobParsons: The *document mode* setting on the *Emulation* tab says *Edge (Default)*. "If possible include links to web pages or a jsfiddle with your questions." - what exactly are you referring to? There is no public version of our software that I could link to, and I have no concrete question that I would not want to solve myself with exactly the developer tools I am asking about :) In any case, I am getting the impression that MSIE dev tools may just be so awfully unstable that they crash/get stuck much more often than not, almost (!) always resulting in the behaviour I have described.

Comment: I am not looking over your shoulder and cannot see what software or addons you have installed on your computer.... IE uses Emulation modes, and if you use earlier version modes, some of the functionality in the IE11 dev tool does not work as expected..that is a know reason for symptoms similar to what you have given. My next suggestion is that you test in noAddons mode....IF you have upgraded from XP, possibly you still have the standalone developer tool (from IE7/8) installed. Start>Run>iexplore.exe -extoff

Comment: @RobParsons: As far as I know, the computer was freshly setup with Windows 8.1 when I got it, not upgraded from XP. I'll check the other things when I'm back to work next year.

Comment: @mapper - try going to a public website like google.com or bing.com and then displaying the dev tool console and executing code, say... type window... Are you using an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), do you already have a debugger from Visual Studio started? viz: do you press f5 from visual studio to debug your web page code? What setting do you have for Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Disable script debugging Other".

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the right hand corner there's a little green triangular arrow. Click it and I think you'll get the results you're looking for.

Comment: same issue when i click the green triangle.